# Creating an ArrayList of an Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file-io, arraylist

This is the first time I work with ArrayList and Arrays at the same time, I'm working on a dictionary from spanish to english, it's like a game, because user can create his/her own study lists, (s)he select which words (s)he wants to add into the study list, he can create as many lists as he wants.

I'm looking for is

**1)** when I create an object of WordsData into another class how can I add the new object with the arrays into the ArrayList, I need to add even boolean, because if true, then the word will be shown into the game, else it won't.

**2)** is it possible that user can choose the name of the file? I mean instead of having "StudyList.txt" user could say "myFirstStudyList.txt" or "lalala.txt" and how could this be done, I tried with:

```
String fileName = "lalala";
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName ".txt"));
```

but It didn't compile.

This is an example of my class, it's bigger but this can help:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

class WordsData implements java.io.Serializable{
String meaning[];
String words[];
boolean add[];
int type;

WordsData(){
    meaning = new String[10];
    words = new String[10];
    add = new boolean[10];
    type = 0;
}
int get_type(){
    return type;
}
void set_type(int t){
    this.type = t;
}
String []get_meaning(){
    meaning = new String[]{
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four",
        "Five",
        "Six",
        "Seven",
        "Eight",
        "Nine",
        "Ten",
    };
    return meaning;
}
String []get_words(){
    words = new String[]{
        "Uno",
        "Dos",
        "Tres",
        "Cuatro",
        "Cinco",
        "Seis",
        "Siete",
        "Ocho",
        "Nueve",
        "Diez"
    }
    return words;
}
boolean []get_add(){
    add = new boolean[]{
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true,
        true
    };
    return add;
}
}
```

This is what I've tried but it's not working or at least I don't know how to do it:

```
WordsData aux = new WordsData();
for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    aux.set_meaning((String)table.getValueAt(j,1), j);
    aux.set_words((String)table.getValueAt(j,2), j);
    aux.set_agregar((boolean)table.getValueAt(j,3), j);
    aux.set_type();
}
study_list.add(aux);
try{
    ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("StudyList.txt"));
    out.writeObject(lista_estudio);
    out.close();
}
catch(Exception exp){
}
```

Thanks in advice, and for the newbie question.

Comment: For the file name part that wouldn't compile, String concatenation requires a + sign in java (fileName + ".txt"), but its typically better to use StringBuilder.

Comment: oh yes @MarkW I just wrote that part, that part isn't on my code, with StringBuild should it work?

Comment: *This is what I've tried but it's not working or at least I don't know how to do it:* What do you mean *it's not working*? Please be more specific. Do you get an Exception? Any compiling errors? Be aware indexes in Java start at `0`, so if your table has 3 columns this line: `(boolean)table.getValueAt(j,3)` will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It's just a guess but it's a pretty common error.

Comment: It should have worked either way Jesus. IE fileName + ".txt"; appends .txt to the end of a string, and using a StringBuilder's .append() function will as well.

Comment: ok I'll check it; and @dic19 getVauleAt, I'm giving the X and Y coordinates of the table, on j=0 (or X=0) I have the ID, it is: 0->ID 1->meaning 2->words 3->add and what it's not working is it adds but I can't figure out how to read it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) when I create an object of WordsData into another class how can I
>   add the new object with the arrays into the ArrayList, I need to add
>   even boolean, because if true, then the word will be shown into the
>   game, else it won't.

This could be achieved by using a combination of `ArrayList#addAll` and `Arrays.asList`

`Arrays.asList` allows you to create a List out of an array.  `ArryaList#addAll` adds all the values from the supplied `Collection` to the instance of `ArrayList`

As to the second part of the question, you could use a second `ArrayList` which contained all the "active" words or an index value of the word to be used that links to the master `ArrayList`

Take a look at the [Collections Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for more details

> 2) is it possible that user can choose the name of the file? I mean
>   instead of having "StudyList.txt" user could say
>   "myFirstStudyList.txt" or "lalala.txt" and how could this be done, I
>   tried with:

Yes. The reason you're having issues is because you forget to concaternate the String value correctly.

Instead of...

```
fileName ".txt"
```

Try using

```
fileName + ".txt"
```

Comment: +1 for the collections part but about 2nd point please note OP's code is actually right: `ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("StudyList.txt"));` OP just made a typo describing what he wants but the code itself is correct. There's no problem in that line. I think you can suggest `JFileChooser` for this question: *"is it possible that user can choose the name of the file?"* instead.

Comment: @dic9 yes, you could use a JFileChooser, t hat would depend on what output paradigm the OP using. As to the file name issue, the code the OP was use was actually String fileName = "lalala"; ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName ".txt")); <---

Comment: ooh ok thanks, I'll check it, and btw could you give me an example or any code on how to create the second ArrayList? I've never worked with them that way.

Comment: Oh I got confused with this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22465207/creating-an-arraylist-of-an-object-array#comment34172004_22465207). And of course JFileChooser is an OP choice, but since he's using JTable it sounds like a good match :)

Comment: @dic19 when I first tried that with ...(fileName + ".txt")); it gave me a compilation error, I just changed to ...("StudyList.txt")); but JFileChooser isn't what I want at all, that works for or instead a FileInputStream instead of FileOutputStream if I'm not wrong, I want user to choose the name of the file, in the example fileName = "lalala", "lalala" is given by user input from a JTextField, I was wondering if that could be possible

Comment: @JesusSanchez Yes, `JFileChooser` is a good choice, to will allow the user to specify a location and name for the file, it will return a `File` reference which you can then use a `FileOutputStream` to write to.  But, yes, you can simply use a `String` from a `JTextField`. `ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName + ".txt"));` should work fine, although I'd question the use of an `ObjectOutputStream`, but that's me...